# User name form validation message

Tags: user-interface, usability

I have a form validation message for the user name field which says the following

Name can only contain alphabets, '.' and ' ' characters

OR should it be

Name can only contain alphabets, dot and space characters

OR should it be

Name can only contain alphabets, dot (".") and space (" ") characters

Which is preferable from a usability perspective assuming the end users has very less exposure to computers.

Comment: You don't allow hyphens? My friend Dr. Burki-Cohen would not be pleased with you. Please don't tell me this unnecessary restriction is to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: wasn't aware of one such possibility, i will add this into the allowed list of characters.

Comment: You also need apostrophes, otherwise Brian O'Malley might be disappointed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use 'letters of the alphabet' not 'alphabets'
- rather than 'characters' ''.'' or ("."), why not just show the character on for instance a different background

So something like:

Name can only contain letters of the alphabet, `.` and spaces

Answer (score 4):

A suggestion: include examples.

```
Name can only contain letters, dots or spaces. 
E.g. <i>Yoda</i>, <i>Han.Solo</i> or <i>Darth Vader</i> ...
```

Comment: +1 for the examples. And for the correct formatting, as I think that listing the characters - maybe with quotation marks and/or parenthesis - kind of misses the point of being helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Name must be allow Alphabet(A to Z or a to z), dot(.), Space and apostrophe:(')

Some time number are allow in the Name field (for exception case).

Maximum 100 characters are allow in the Full Name field (Firstname =50  and Lastname =50)

Comment: It's possible to have hyphenated names - there's an example given in the comments on the question.